# Standardizing Date Variable in R

Tags: r, date

I have various data sources and each data source has a different convention on naming dates.

Example:

Some are: 
May 16,2017 as  Character type

While others are: 
16/05/2017 as Date type

Is it possible to write a code that would coerce everything including those in character to dd/mm/yyyy date format?

Answer (score 0):

We could use the `parse_date_time` from `lubridate` which takes multiple formats

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(str1, c("mdy", "dmy"))
#[1] "2017-05-16 UTC" "2017-05-16 UTC"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("May 16,2017", "16/05/2017")
```